# Why this map.put() is overwriting the existing values event though map.containskey() returns false?

Tags: java

There might be a silly mistake that I am unable to note, but in the code below whenever I put a new key,value pair, it replaces all other values for existing keys as well. I did a check to see if it already contains the key, but the check map.containsKey() always returns false as it should, then what is wrong here?

```
      while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                String[] DZs;
                if (id%2==0){
                 String[] values=line.split(" ");
                    String[] low=values[0].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");//lower limit array of subs
                    String[] high=values[1].replace("[", "").replace("]","").split(",");//upper limit of subs
                    assert low.length==high.length;
                    int[] lowdim=new int[low.length];
                    int[] highdim=new int[high.length];
                    for(int i=0;i<low.length;i++){
                       lowdim[i]=Integer.parseInt(low[i].trim());
                       highdim[i]=Integer.parseInt(high[i].trim());
                    }
                    lowerBound=lowdim;
                    upperBound=highdim;
                    id++;
              }
              else{
               id++;
               DZs=line.split(" ");
               if (!subDzs.isEmpty()){
                        subDzs.clear();
                    }
                    for(String dz:DZs){
                        subDzs.add(dz);
                    }
                    Participant sub=new Participant(lowerBound,upperBound);
                    allSubs.add(sub);
                    System.out.println("Map contains key? " +subToDz.containsKey(sub));//returns false
                    subToDz.put(sub,subDzs);//overwrites existing values everytime new key,value is put
              }
            }
```

Comment: Can you cut the code down to what is relevant to the question? In particular you haven't included what `sub` is or how it is modified/set. How to you know it is being modified?

Comment: `subDzs` is a reference to an object so when you add it to the Map, you are only adding that reference, not a copy of the Object it references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `subDzs` is. Probably a `List`. Anyway, you are using the same value object for all your `put` statements. Each time you call `subDzs.clear()`, you are clearing the values of all the entries in your map. You should assign a new instance (of whatever type it is) to `subDzs` before putting it in the `Map`.

Replace

```
           if (!subDzs.isEmpty()){
               subDzs.clear();
           }
           for(String dz:DZs){
               subDzs.add(dz);
           }
           Participant sub=new Participant(lowerBound,upperBound);
           allSubs.add(sub);
           System.out.println("Map contains key? " +subToDz.containsKey(sub));//returns false
           subToDz.put(sub,subDzs);//overwrites existing values everytime new key,value is put
```

with

```
           subDzs = new ... // create a new instance
           for(String dz:DZs){
               subDzs.add(dz);
           }
           Participant sub=new Participant(lowerBound,upperBound);
           allSubs.add(sub);
           System.out.println("Map contains key? " +subToDz.containsKey(sub));
           subToDz.put(sub,subDzs);
```

Comment: How did i not see that!! Thanks a lot.